# Boolean column in GIST index

Tags: postgresql

I have the below table in postgres12

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    my_id      BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    during     daterange NOT NULL,
    is_primary BOOLEAN   NOT NULL,
    data       JSONB,
    EXCLUDE USING gist(my_id WITH =, int4(is_primary) WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

I guess it works as intended. But I think **int4(is_primary)** is an ugly hack to get my boolean in the exclude clause. Is there a less obscure way to write this and get the same functionality?

Comment: You can write the cast in a different way, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a cast